# NSUserDefault storing an NSArray of Custom Object with NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, nsarray, nsuserdefaults, nscoding

I have seen good examples on how to store custom objects to an array inside NSUserDefault. My question is, how can I do this if my Custom Object has an array as its property.

I looked at an example given which got me this, however courses is an NSMutableArray.

```
@implementation ClassNames
@synthesize courses;
@synthesize name;


- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder;
{
    [coder encodeObject:courses forKey:@"courses"];
    [coder encodeObject:name forKey:@"name"];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder;
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil)
    {
        courses = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"courses"] ;
        name = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"name"] ;
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

This is what I call when I want to save and load classes

```
- (NSMutableArray *)loadClasses{
    NSUserDefaults *currentDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData *dataRepresentingSavedArray = [currentDefaults objectForKey:@"classes"];
    if (dataRepresentingSavedArray != nil)
    {
        NSArray *oldSavedArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:dataRepresentingSavedArray];
        if (oldSavedArray != nil)
            return [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:oldSavedArray];
        else
            return [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return nil;

 }




- (void)saveClasses:(ClassNames *)classes
{
    NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    [standardUserDefaults setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:classes] forKey:@"classes"];
    [standardUserDefaults synchronize];

}
```

The NSMutableArray "courses" which is in ClassNames is an NSMutableArray of NSStrings.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
  NSString *docsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
  NSString *filename = [docsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test"];   

 //store the array

 [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:myArray toFile:filename];

//get the array

 NSMutableArray* myArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:filename];
```

Comment: I need to be able to store a array of custom objects. Each object has an array.  Are you saying this will work with storing the custom object, which contains a array as a property of it.

Comment: It will to some extent, what is the problem that your are facing when u use NSKeyedArchiver. Have u tried something like this //store the array
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:myArray toFile:@"someFile"];

//load the array
NSMutableArray* myArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:@"someFile"];